# If we store a NSMutableDictionary into a NSDictionary, can we later use it again as a NSMutableDictionary?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

If we replace a NSDictionary instance variable with a NSMutableDictionary that we create, can we later use it again as a NSMutableDictionary by casting it as a NSDictionary?

Example:

create and store the NSMutableDictionary into the NSDictionary slot

```
NSMutableDictionary *muta = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:NSArray forKeys:NSArray];
Object.nsDictionary = muta;
```

Get the dictionary later

```
NSMutableDictionary *muta2 = (NSMutableDictionary*) Object.nsDictionary;
//Do stuff like Add objects with it
[muta2 setObject:id forKey@"key"];
```

Do we have to recreate a NSMutableDictionary from the NSDictionary we pull from the object or does it retain it's "mutability"? Can you please tell me why a subclassed object will or will not retain its specific methods and properties when replacing a generic super class?

Comment: "Casting" does not change the type of an object.

Comment: The property `nsDictionary` should be typed as a `NSMutableDictionary*` if it is to be used as one.

Answer (score 3):

If your property is declared as `NSDictionary` then you shouldn't make any assumptions about whether it is actually mutable or not.

The proper code should be:

```
NSMutableDictionary *muta2 = [Object.nsDictionary mutableCopy];
```

This works regardless of what type of dictionary is actually stored in the property.

Comment: It's worth noting that this isn't because having the variable be typed as NSDictionary magically transforms the object into an NSDictionary, but that the class is *within its rights* to make an immutable copy of the dictionary, and many classes do.

Answer (score 0):

In your question you are confusing two different things: you refer to assigning to an *instance variable* but show code which shows assigning to a *property*. These are not the same. You are also appear to be misunderstanding *assignment* by referring to it as *replacing* an object.

In Objective-C (and many other, but not all, languages) an *object* is referred to by a *reference*. It is these references which are *assigned* into variables. So for example in:

```
NSMutableDictionary *a = [NSMutableDictionary new];
NSMutableDictionary *b = a;
```

The right hand side of the first assignment is an expression which creates a new object and returns a reference to that object. This reference is then stored into the variable `a`. The second line copies the *reference*, **not** the object, stored in `a` and stores into into the variable `b`.

After these two lines one object and two variables have been created, and both variables reference *exactly the same* object. Assignment of a reference to an object *does not change the object it refers to*. So if we now change the code to:

```
NSMutableDictionary *a = [NSMutableDictionary new];
NSDictionary *b = a;
```

We still have one object and two variables created, and both still refer to exactly the same object. The assignment in this case is allowed as `NSMutableDictionary` is a *subclass* of `NSDictionary` - that is an object of type `NSMutableDictionary` is also of type `NSDictionary`, it provides all the same behaviour as the latter.

From your question "Can you please tell me why a subclassed object will or will not retain its specific methods and properties when replacing a generic super class?" you need to read up on *inheritance* and understand how subclassing works.

Once you've stored a reference to a subclass into a superclass typed variables, `a` into `b` in the above code, while you haven't changed the referenced object in anyway you have lost the immediate knowledge that the reference is in fact to an object of the subclass - all you can immediately state about a reference stored in `b` above is that it refers to an object which is at least an `NSDictionary`, but *may* be of any subclass of `NSDictionary`.

If you are *absolutely sure*, or just like writing programs that break, you can tell the compiler to trust you that `b` contains a reference to an `NSMutableDictionary` by using a *cast*:

```
NSMutableDictionary *c = (NSMutableDictionary *)b;
```

Do this and the compiler trusts you, but if `b` does not contain a reference to an `NSMutableDictionary` then your subsequent usage of `c` will probably be invalid and your program will break.

What you need to do is to test whether the reference refers to an `NSMutableDictionary` or not, and you do this with the method `isKindOfClass:`:

```
if ([b isKindOfClass:NSMutableDictionary.class])
{
   // b refers to an NSMutableDictionary
   NSMutableDictionary *c = (NSMutableDictionary *)b;
   // do something with c
}
else
{
   // b does not refer to an NSMutableDictionary
   // handle this case
}
```

Back to *properties*: a property is two methods (assuming read-write, you can have read-only properties), a *getter* and a *setter*, which combine to provide an abstraction of a *variable* - you can "read" and "assign" to them using dot notation in expressions. However as they call a method, rather than performing direct reads or assignments to a variable, that method can change was is read or assigned. In particular an object typed property declared with the *copy* attribute will make a copy of the *object* that is reference. For example:

```
@property (copy) NSDictionary *c;

...

NSMutableDictionary *a = [NSMutableDictionary new];
NSDictionary *b = a;
self.c = a;
```

then `a` & `b` both refer to the *same* object which is an instance of `NSMutableDictionary`; while, due to the `copy` attribute`,`c`refers to a *distinct* object which is an instance of`NSDictionary`.

You can now see why using *instance variable* and *property* interchangeably in your question is not right - what is assigned can be different depending on whether the assignment is to a variable or a property.

You should read up on objects, object references, inheritance and properties.

HTH.